# Using or with C# query to get a list/array for that result

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Hello currently I have this code implemented:

```
testing = //more querying code that takes multiple tables and joins them together 
          //to get info from multiple tables
          let id = //id value 
          from test in table
          where test.PropertyID == 30 || test.PropertyID == 3
          select new { id_for_value, 
          test.Value, 
           //returns additional stuff from other tables as well 
          }
```

This currently creates two separate inputs ex( `testing = [[0, "property3"],[0, "property30"]]`) but I want them to be within the same entry (`testing = [0, [property3, property30]]`.

I tried seeing if I could do `test.Value.toArray()` but that is not possible

The id_for_value may have duplicates for different entries as it is only linked to the `test.value` but is not unique for each entry

Comment: It _sounds_ like you want to **group** the result, but it's hard to tell with so little information about your input data and expected results....

Comment: You need to group by id, but I've never bothered with the query comprehension syntax so someone else will need to show you what that looks like.

Comment: `var result = testing.GroupBy(t => t.id, (id, values) => new {id, values.ToArray()});`

Comment: I should have clarified that there are several fields additional fields that are being selected and the query is quite long with multiple tables. Unfortunately the id just corresponds to the `test.Value` but is not unique across the entries as there is a lot of information coming across different tables

Comment: Then you need to update the question to include that complexity